# NonRecursive Sets

Tags: logic, computability

I'm trying to show that the following are nonrecursive:

1. $\{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid \phi_x(y) \uparrow\}$
2. $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \mid \phi_x = \phi_y\}$
3. $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \mid y \in \operatorname{im}(\phi_x)\}$
4. $\{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 0 \in \operatorname{im}(\phi_x)\}$
5. $\{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid \operatorname{im}(\phi_x)\mbox{ is infinite}\}$

So, to show a set is non-recursive, it boils down to showing that its characteristic function is non-recursive. Can someone explain how that helps in this case?

I do not know Rice's theorem yet, and for the first one:

1) Is the proof on page 102 of theorem 1.3 in Cultand sufficient?

2) Is this essentially the proof of theorem 1.5 in Cutland, page 104?

3) I don't see this in Cutland page 103-105

For 4 and 5, an someone provide a proof here? I am confused on the first few. Thanks

Comment: What is $y$ in the first one?

Comment: Why do you want to show these *five* particular sets are not recursive? The best questions here describe how the questions was encountered and what the asker has already tried.  This question seems unmotivated to me, because I don't see a direct connection between the five sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you allowed by way of background? If you are allowed to appeal to the industrial-strength Rice's Theorem, then things are easy. If you are having to work from closer to first principles then you've a lot of ground to cover.

Qn 1 is the halting problem (in *very* thin disguise), so you should already be able to answer this. [Shouldn't it be: is $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \mid \phi_x(y)\!\uparrow\}$ recursive?]

Qn 2 is a bit tougher. Have a look at Cutland's classic book *Computability* where he proves this in a page-long proof on pp. 103-104. (Or  see Carl Mummett's comment for a snappier argument).

Qn 3 is dealt with by Cutland on pp. 104-105.

(With the techniques we need for those first three questions mastered, you should be able to do the other two questions!)

Comment: I don't know how Cutland does #2, but it is not so bad. Let $z$ be an index such that $\phi_z(0)$ converges to 0 and $\phi_z(n+1)$ diverges for all $n$. There is an immediate many-one reduction from the set $K_0$ of $x$ such that $\phi_x(0)$ converges to the set $Z$ of $x'$ such that $\phi_{x'} = \phi_z$. To compute $\phi_{x'}(0)$, compute $\phi_x(0)$ and then return 0; to compute $\phi_{x'}(n+1)$ just don't return anything. Because the $K_0$ is not computable, $Z$ must also not be computable. But if set 2 was computble then $Z$ would be computable.

Comment: @CarlMummert Nice and snappy!

Comment: @PeterSmith, I traced through the book of Cutland but cannot seem t o understand the last 2. I added some comment on the first three

Comment: @PeterSmith: I'm trying to do this without Rice's theorem